# Dynamic analysis tools in windows

Tags: risk-analysis, audit

I'm sorry, i'm newbie in security, i'm looking for a software that detect changes in the whole operating system during its execution, that's helps analysing the behaviour of malicious software to know its impact in OS ?

I've already seen this kind of software but i have forgot his name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use [SysInternals](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/SysinternalsSuite.zip) in general and [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) (`procmon.exe`) specifically to monitor what an application does in the system. It will give you all registry operations, DLL operations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try [RegShot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/). I've had a lot of success with it for comparing pre- and post-registry modifications.